# MPMusicPlayerController's setNowPlayingItem doesn't work in SWIFT

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am creating a music player to play the selected item when a user taps on the tableview cell using MPMusicPlayerController's setNowPlayingItem.
The following code works well in Objective C, But when I tried to convert this into swift it doesn't works. Can anybody suggest what is the equivalent for the following code in SWIFT ?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MPMediaItem *song = self.songs[indexPath.row];
    [self.musicPlayer setNowPlayingItem:song];
    [self.musicPlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution

```
    var mySongs = [MPMediaItemCollection]()
    var songsQry = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
    songsQry.groupingType = MPMediaGrouping.Title
    mySongs = songsQry.collections as [MPMediaItemCollection]
    var playQueue = MPMediaItemCollection(items: mySongs)


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        var currentSong: MPMediaItem
        currentSong = songs[indexPath.row].representativeItem
        let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
        musicPlayer.setQueueWithItemCollection(playQueue)
        musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem = currentSong
        musicPlayer.play()
}
```